# Return a view from a different area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, areas

I have my ASP.NET MVC 2 application divided into few areas. One of them is a default area in the main catalog, and the other is an `Account` area in the Areas catalog. Now, the problem is that I need to use the same view in controllers from both of these areas.

If they were in the same area, I would just `return View("ViewName")`, but what can I do to return a view from my default area in a controller from my `Account` area? Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note, you can stick this view in the `~/Views/Shared` folder and just call `return View("ViewName")` from any controller/area.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could specify the relative location of the view:

```
return View("~/Views/YourArea/YourController/YourView.aspx");
```

But when a view is shared among multiple areas I would recommend you to use the `~/Views/Shared` folder which serves better this purpose.

Comment: Thank you Darin - I will try this one.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but still a relevant issue in MVC I think, so here is how I solve it in a DRY fashion that lets you easily change the server path, and have all your dependent actions update automatically:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{

    private ActionResult FooView(string name, string extension = "cshtml") { 
        return View("~/Areas/Bar/Views/Foo/" + name + "." + extension); }
    }


    public ActionResult SomeAction(){

      return FooView("AreaSpecificViewName");

    }

    public ActionResult SomeOtherAction(){

      return FooView("AnotherAreaSpecificViewName", "aspx");

    }

}
```

This is neat because it defaults to Razor (`.cshtml`) View files, but it can be set explicitly by supplying the second parameter, as seen in `SomeOtherAction()`.

It's simple but handy, especially during development when the path of your Area might change or something.

Hope that helps someone.